# -16 represents acceleration?

Tags: kinematics, acceleration, projectile

> A physics teacher put a ball at the top of a ramp and let it roll down toward the floor. The class determined that the height of the ball could be represented by the equation, $h=-16t^2+4$, where the height, $h,$ is measured in feet from the ground and time, $t,$ is in seconds.

I know $4$ is the starting point of the ball, and $-16$ is the slope, but what does the $-16$ represent (i.e. acceleration).

Comment: Note, that the word "slope" only makes sense for linear curves. The coefficient in front of a squared variable such as $t^2$ is just a coefficient, not the slope of any curve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second derivative of the position is acceleration, which in this case is $-32$. This is the gravitational acceleration near the surface of the earth in $\text{ft} / \text{s}^2$.

---

Also, $-16$ is *not* the slope. The slope (read: velocity) at time $t$ is $-32t$ is variable.